# Active Record - Find and Update (only if object exists)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have an id of a record that may or may not exist in the database.

What i want to do is update an attribute of the record in the database only if it exists, otherwise ignore it.

Now i know i can do something like:

```
model = Model.find_by_id(id)
if model
     model.update_attribute(something: something)
end
```

But i was wondering if there's something nicer that doesn't involve 2 queries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Model.update_all({:something => 'something'}, {:id => id})
```

For eg:

```
User.update_all({:first_name => 's'}, {:id => 1000})
```

will produce the query

```
UPDATE "users" SET "first_name" = 's' WHERE "users"."id" = 1000
```

Answer (score 4):

If you dont have the object to update and you want to trigger the AR callbacks after update then this will make two sql queries but nice looking:

`Model.update(id, {something: something})`

If you dont bothered with the callbacks, you can use:

`Model.update_all({something: something}, {id: id})`

Comment: If you use Model.update, how do you tell if the update was successful?